# Conditional JSR-303 validation based on enclosed class type

Tags: java, spring, validation

How can I change validation rules based on which class given bean is enclosed in?
Example:

```
public class ParentA {
    @Valid
    private Child c;
}
public class ParentB {
    @Valid
    private Child c;
}
public class Child {
    @NotNull // when in ParentA
    @Null // when in ParentB
    private String name;
}
```

There are validation groups, however, I do not know how to apply them in this case. Can I specify the following: if validating ParentA then apply GroupA for its fields, hopefully by some annotation and without instanceof? I really do not want to create two types ChildA and ChildB with different validation annotations. I am building REST service with spring 4. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class ParentA {
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=ParentA.class)
    private Child c;
}

public class ParentB {
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=ParentB.class)
    private Child c;
}

public class Child {
    @NotNull(groups=ParentA.class)
    @Null(groups=ParentB.class)
    private String name;
}
```

You can find more info and other examples in [hibernate validator reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#section-group-conversion)